# Animate cclayergradient colors

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to animate the colors of a CCLayerGradient over time?
I'm thinking of some CC*** function like CCBezierTo...
Is there something to animate arbitrary values of an object?

Comment: `CCTintTo` works, but only changes ".color". I'd need to change ".endColor" as well.

Comment: I wrote a `CCTintGradientTo` class. It takes not only one set of rgb, but another set of rgb for the end color. Works great. Though I'm really ignoring the `CCRGBAProtocol` something protocol, so it only works with `CCGradientLayer` really. I couldn't get `CCActionTween` to work with this as the color values aren't properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CCActionTween](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/KoboldTouch/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_action_tween.html) for this. It allows you to change the value of a property over time by providing the property's name.

Only works with integral data types such as int, float but not structs such as CGPoint, CGRect. But it's easy enough to create a category with (for example) positionX and positionY properties which update the corresponding x/y value of a CGPoint property.